# Next.js router pushes wrong route

Tags: next.js

I'm wokring on role-based auth in Next.js app. Currently I have two roles: admin and user.

I have pages structure that looks like this:

```
 ┣ admin
 ┃ ┣ edit.tsx
 ┃ ┗ profile.tsx
 ┣ user
 ┃ ┗┣ edit.tsx
 ┃ ┗ profile.tsx
 ┣ _app.tsx
 ┣ index.tsx
```

And I have enum with routes

```
enum ADMIN_ROUTES {
  PROFILE = 'admin/profile',
  EDIT = 'admin/edit',

}
```

The problem is when I use `router.push(ADMIN_ROUTES.PROFILE)` / `router.push(ADMIN_ROUTES.EDIT)` it returns `admin/admin/profile` / `admin/admin/edit` instead of `admin/profile` / `admin/edit`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to use absolute routing (or PUBLIC_API prefix) for const routes, because what you write looks pretty ok and legit resolution of relative paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  PROFILE = '/admin/profile',
  EDIT = '/admin/edit',
```

instead of

```
 PROFILE = 'admin/profile',
 EDIT = 'admin/edit',
```

Fixed the issue